# how can I solve "Positional argument cannot appear after keyword arguments" problem in Selenium Webdriver find_element method?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I trying to learn Selenium Webdriver basics from the official website [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/) , I create a python file and a html file in the same folder, and I tried to use **find_element()**method and search elements by **CLASS_NAME**, but I always get this problem
**[{"message": "Positional argument cannot appear after keyword arguments","source": "Pylance"}]**. this is the **python** code

```
#find web elements in snappit.html file
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def test_locators():

    driver=webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
    driver.get("file:///F:/Ahmad/python_test/selenium_test/snappit.html")
    element = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, "information")

test_locators()
```

and this is the **html** code, the two files in the same folder

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
.information {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<h2>Contact Selenium</h2>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m" />Male &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="f" />Female <br>
  <br>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input class="information" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Jane"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input class="information" type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <label for="newsletter">Newsletter:</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="1" /><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>To know more about Selenium, visit the official page 
<a href ="www.selenium.dev">Selenium Official Page</a> 
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried **'information'** , **"information"** but I get the same problem.
I also tried  **name="information"** but I face another problem that the method don't have name attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to declare the first element as a keyword. You can just make both positional arguments by changing that line of code to

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "information")
```

Comment: Thanks @Jesse Sealand  this solution works very well